# Loop bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, sleep, icalendar

I have a bash shell script that outputs an iCal event using iCal Buddy which displays 2 events like:

- Event1 Title
- Event1 Date
- Event2 Title
- Event2 Date

I would like to have the script output like:

- Event Title
- Event Date

(wait 10 seconds) clear the Event Title, Event Date, then output the next Event Title, Event Date (wait 10 seconds) then loop back to the first Event and continue looping. I've tried using the command followed by sleep 10, and repeating the command with | head -n 4 | tail -n 2, although then it only outputs the second Event.

How can I do this? (my shell script is below) Thanks!

```
/usr/local/bin/icalBuddy -npn -nc -n -iep "title,datetime" -b "★ "  -ps "| ★\n|" -po "title,datetime" -nrd -df "%a, %b %e" eventsToday+2 | cut -c 1-33
```

2

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand you, this should do what you want:

```
while true
do
    clear
    command | pipeline | head -n 2
    sleep 10
    clear
    command | pipeline | head -n 4 | tail -n 2
    sleep 10
done
```

Where "command | pipeline" represents the `icalBuddy` and `cut` in your question.